# Measure TCP thruoghput while streaming video

Tags: tcp, throughput, iperf3

I am trying to measure TCP throughput using Iperf3 tool. What I am doing is this:

1- open three connections in iperf, -each with different client- for 900 seconds (the time of video)

2-  run VLC to stream video from those 3 clients( this is done using different connections from that related to iperf)

The Iperf connections consume the bandwidth and affects the quality of the video.
what I need is:

Is there a way that I can measure the bandwidth of the 3 clients without sending much data that affects the quality of the video ?

Comment: You can use tcpdump to capture the tcp headers of all the packets and process it offline either using wireshark or tcptrace. I would do the capture on the receiver side.

Comment: I need online estimation, because I decide which one should I use it for streaming. this is done while the video playing

Comment: Why do you need online estimation? Are you using the throughput as input to an algorithm?

Comment: yes. and based on that value, I decide which dash server should I use for streaming.

Comment: I think you need to measure the throughput in the application. I did some DASH experimentation a while ago. Take a look at https://github.com/pari685/AStream. Maybe this helps